# The meaning of Fifo's Fraud

Tags: meaning

Based on my search, it seems "FIFO" in "[Fifo's fraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam)" means "First In, First Out". I hope I am wrong because I don't see how "First In, First Out" has to do with frauds. Please help me understand the meaning of this expression - thank you!

"There are many variations of this type of scam, including the 419 scam (also known as the Nigerian Prince scam), the Spanish Prisoner scam, the black money scam, Fifo's Fraud and the Detroit-Buffalo scam."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your research is correct at all.

FIFO as an acronym (note the capitalisation) has a number of meanings, including "first in, first out", and also "fly in, fly out".

I have no reason to think that any of these relate to 'Fifo's Fraud'. Note that it is not capitalised, and is also used in possessive form. It isn't an 'expression' but seems to be simply the name given to one variant of a particular type of internet scam. It may have been the name used in the emails by the scammer, I really don't know, and I can't seem to find any reference to it, but it certainly isn't an English word requiring definition.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!